# Problems making JavaFX TextField and TextArea editable

Tags: javafx-2

I have a JavaFX Application which opens an auxiliary `Stage`. The `Stage` itself contains a `TextArea` and a `TextField`, both marked as editable in Scene Builder, and neither of them with any bindings for the `TextProperty` (as far as I know). Even so, I am unable to type anything into these fields.

What might be blocking the editing?

The relevant FXML is as follows:

```
<HBox prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
  <children>
    <Label prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="89.0" text="Query name:" textAlignment="RIGHT" />
    <TextField fx:id="queryNameTextField" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="518.0" />
  </children>
</HBox>
```

With some further tinkering I have noticed that the new window I open does not always have focus, even when the `TextField` itself does! I say this because the title of the window is greyed out.

Comment: Can you focus on them? i.e. are they grayed out or can see caret on them? Post the generated FXML.

Comment: Yes, I can focus them. I have added a snippet of the FXML!

Comment: There maybe event filters on the parent layouts. Otherwise sorry you will need to provide MCVE.

Comment: Have you tried adjusting the Modality of your auxiliary window via `aux.initModality(Modality)`?